# Using Cache Section with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am attempting to use cache sections and recieve error

```
   Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class
 'Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedStore' does not have a method 'section' in   
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php line 196
```

from my Code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class SimpleSearchController extends BaseController{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        Cache::forever('test', 'this is a saved test cached vaclue');

        $john = ['ming','chin','zao'];
        Cache::section('people_d')->forever('John', $john);

        }
```

any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Additional information --- looking at the Repo https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Cache
it seems I am missing 2 files
RedisSection.php  and Section.php.

Comment: Found solution ... I had
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
in composar.json
changing to 
    "laravel/framework": "dev-master",
then deleting vendor directory / running composar install fixed the issue

Comment: Changing it to `dev-master` is a terrible idea. Go for `4.*` at most if you don't want your project broken.